# jqGrid with localArray - Inline Navigation : call custom function on clicking add, save & delete row buttons

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am using jqGrid with localArray data. I am fetching this array from azure db and binging to grid.
After this on manipulation of every single row, I am planning to update it in DB.

I am using inline navigation bar. On clicking of "add row", "save row" & "delete row" button I want to call my custom function and then would like to save/delete data in DB from that function.

**First I would like to know whether my design is correct and scalable or not.**

At present, I am able to call custom function on click of save button using "aftersavefunc" parameter.

**Second, please let me know which parameter I have to set for "delete row" button.
I think for "add row", same parameter can work as we have to click "save row" button to save row.**

My code is as below for reference :

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: myData,
        height: "auto",
        colNames: ['RowNo', 'RouteId', 'Area', 'BusStop', 'Seater', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Timing', 'FromTo', 'KeyPoint'],
        colModel: [
                  { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 50, sortable: false },
                  { name: 'RouteId', index: 'RouteId', width: 50, sortable: false },
                  { name: 'Area', index: 'Area', width: 130, sortable: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },

              ],
        multiselect: false,
        rownumbers: false,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Bus Schedule Data",
        editurl: "clientArray",
        restoreAfterSelect: false,
        loadonce: true

    });
    var rowid;
    var inlineparams = {
        addParams: { useFormatter: false },
        editParams: {
            aftersavefunc: function (id) {
                var rowData = jQuery('#list4').jqGrid('getRowData', id);
                ScheduleTable.update({ id: 1, Area: rowData.Area.toString() });
            }
        },
        add: true,
        edit: true,
        save: true,
        cancel: true,
        del: true
    };

    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager1", { edit: false, save: false, add: false, cancel: false, del: false });
    jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#pager1", inlineparams);
    jQuery('#list4').jqGrid("saveRow", id, {
        keys: false,
        url: "clientArray"
    });
```

Comment: @oleg : Please take a look and reply. It will be a great help.

Comment: I don't understand *why* you don't want to use Ajax to communicate with backend which get/save the data in azure db? It seems to me that the problem which you describes exist only because you have chosen `datatype: "local"` and `editurl: "clientArray"`. You can use `aftersavefunc`, but you will have problems with implementing error handling. You first save the data locally and then you try to update the data in the database.